# Prove that the unit ball in $X$ is not compact

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $X$ bet the set of all sequences $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in
>   $\mathbb R$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$. For any $\{a_n\},
>  \{b_n\} \subset X$, we define a metric
>
> $$d(\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}) = \sup\{|a_n - b_n|, n = 1,2,\dots \}$$
>
> Prove that the unit ball $\{\{a_n\}\in X: d(\{a_n\}, 0) = \sup_{n \in
>  \mathbb N} |a_n| \le 1\}$ in $X$ is not compact

I think this unit ball is both bounded and closed in metric space, so it is compact. But the question asks me to prove that it is not compact. Please help.

Comment: In general, in metric spaces, closed and bounded subsets need not be compact. That is something remarkable about $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with suitable metrics, e.g. the Euclidean metric). In particular, that characterisation does not hold in $X$.

Comment: @DanielFischer that begs the question, why is $\mathbb R^n$ so special? What properties should a metric space have to ensure that the Heine Borel theorem holds?

Comment: The correct generalization to other metric spaces is "complete and totally bounded". Plain old boundedness isn't useful, because every metric space is bounded in a metric that is equivalent to a given metric. The metric essentially provides *local* information, not really global.

Comment: In a metric space, the closed unit ball is compact if and only if the space is finite dimensional. One direction may be proved by the Riesz Lemma and the other one follows by Heine-Borel.

Comment: What book is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the more intuitive definitions/characterizations of *compactness* in a metric space $(X,d)$ is the following:

A set $K \subseteq X$ is compact if and only if every sequence $\{a_k\} \subseteq K$ has a convergent subsequence.

So in order to show that the unit ball in the space of all sequences is not compact, you have to find a sequence (of sequences) in the unit ball that does not contain a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 3):

If $K$ is a compact set in a Hausdorff space, the only closed discrete subsets of $K$ are the finite sets.

The infinitely many sequences $s_n$ where
$$
s_n(n)=1,\qquad \text{$s_n(m)=0$ for all $m\neq n$}
$$
form a closed, discrete, but infinite subset of the unit ball in the space of all convergent sequences, implying the latter is not compact.

Comment: I think you mean closed discrete subsets.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: Absolutely. Edited, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For $S\subseteq \mathbb N$ let
$$ a^{(S)}_n=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $n\in S$}\\-1&\text{if $n\notin S$}\end{cases}$$
Then for any sequence $a\in X$ we have $d(a,a^{(S)})<2$ for $S=\{\,n\in \mathbb N\mid a_n>0\,\}$. Hence 
$$\tag1X=\bigcup_{S\subseteq \mathbb N} B(a^{(S)},2).$$
Consider a finite subcover $$\tag2B(a^{(S_1)},2)\cup \ldots \cup B(a^{(S_m)},2)$$
and let $T=\{\,n\in\mathbb N\mid 1\le n\le m, n\notin S_n\,\}$. Then $d(a^{(T)},a^{(S_n)})=2$ for $1\le n\le m$, so that $a^{(T)}$ is not covered by $(2)$.

*Remark:* Apparently $(1)$ doesn't even allow a countable subcover.

Answer (score -1):

Consider 0= (0,0,0,……………) € l2
Consider the closed ball, B [0,1].
Clearly B [0,1] is a closed and bounded subset of l2 . (Any closed ball in a metric space is a closed set and diam B[0,1]

Comment: It is not true that a closed and bounded subset of a metric space is compact; this property is one of the things that makes $\Bbb R^n$ special. The above is a standard counterexample. The general version is that complete and totally bounded subsets of a metric space are compact.